# Creating a select tag with options in JQUERY

Tags: jquery

Is it possible to create a select tag with options in JQuery.

```
            $("<select id="jSelect">
        <option value="1">String</option>
        <option value="2">Number</option>
        <option value="3">Date</option>
    </select>").appendTo(".menu li")
```

Should this work? Its not working for me.

Answer (score 2):

You're using strings wrong. You have double quotes in dubble quoted strings, try this instead, also string in javascript don't span multiple lines.

```
    $(' <select id="jSelect">'+
            '<option value="1">String</option>'+
           '<option value="2">Number</option>'+
            '<option value="3">Date</option>'+
    '</select>').appendTo(".menu li")
```

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
var optionList = ["String", "Number" ,  "Date"];
var combo = $("<select>").attr("id", "jSelect");
$.each(optionList, function (j, el1) 
    {
    combo.append("<option>" + el1 + "</option>");
    });
combo.appendTo(".menu li");
```